# How to call javascript or jquery function inside dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select name = 'category' id='category'>
    <option value="a">A <a href="" class = "edit" id ='1'> Click here to edit </a> </option>
    <option value="b">B <a href="" class = "edit" id ='b'> Click here to edit </a> </option>
</select>
```

I am trying like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.edit', editfunction);

function editfunction() {
    alert('hi');
    //call here ajax code 
}
```

Comment: what you exactly want to achieve, provide more details about your query

Comment: I want to edit category at run time. i need to change a to another value like ali

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your HTML is invalid; you cannot have `a` elements inside an `option`:

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

To do what you require you can hook to the `change` event of the `select`, not the `click` of the `a` within the `option`. You can then use `$(this).val()` to get the selected value in `editFunction()`:

```
$(document).on('change', '#category', editfunction);

function editfunction() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    // AJAX...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
$('#category').on('change', function(){
   editfunction( $(this).val() );
 })

function editfunction(val){
   // Make your ajax call here
}
```

And You actually dont need the  tag inside  to make this happen

[I think this is what u want JSFIDDLE example](https://jsfiddle.net/rovg5a37/1/)

Comment: i need to edit the value of drop down like i add the category name appla i make a mistake in its spelling. when i select the option i see the spelling is wrong or need to change . then i want to edit by click on edit anchor tag, is it possible in any way?